# preprocessing series folders to pass to bash script as individual arguments and submitting jobs in an array

Tags: python, bash, cluster-computing

Please forgive my inexperience with bash:

I need to process a series of large files in a restricted array i.e. only 2 jobs will be able to run simultaneously:

```
qsub -t 1-[number of folders to process] -tc 2 analysis.sh # tc restricts to 2 jobs at any given time
```

I have a series of folders- that I need to pass as arguments to analysis.sh

```
ls /storage/projects/H1_Linker_data/raw_sequence_data/

directory 1
directory 2
....
```

Each of these folders contains a pair of large files that I have to pass as an argument to a bash script in the above directory.

### python initialising analysis.sh and passing arguments

```
import os
import subprocess
import re
list=os.listdir('/storage/projects/H1_Linker_data/raw_sequence_data/')
for i in xrange(0,len(list)):
    dir=list[i]
    files_OI=os.listdir('/storage/projects/teif/mESC/chris_calculations/H1_Linker_data/raw_sequence_data/'+dir)
    os.system('chmod +x ../analysis.sh')
    subprocess.call(['../analysis.sh', '/storage/projects/H1_Linker_data/raw_sequence_data/'+dir+'/'+files_OI[1], 
    '/storage/projects/H1_Linker_data/raw_sequence_data/'+dir+'/'+files_OI[2], dir])
```

Above I basically make a list of all the folders in a parent directory and then pass both the files in each folder as arguments to the bash script in the above directory after enabling the bash script with chmod.

### bash processing

```
echo ${1}
echo ${2}
echo ${3}
....... future processing
```

All of the above works, submitting the jobs sequentially, one after the other. But I would prefer to submit these jobs in a restricted array so that I can have a set number running on the cluster at any given time, to speed things up.

### Possible solution

Is it possible to write the folder names and their contents to a file as follows:

```
head list_of_files.txt

directory 1    file 1    file 2
directory 2    file 1    file 2
directory 3    file 1    file 2
directory 4    file 1    file 2
```

and then have a bash/python script read this file and pass the arguments to analysis.sh... as below:

```
while read list_of_files.txt....
#readlines and take folders and files as arguments
echo ${1}
echo ${2}
echo ${3}
qsub -t 1-[number of lines in list_of_folders.txt] -tc 2 analysis.sh $1 $2 $3
```

Again apologies for the inexperience in bash.... I would appreciate a way to do this purely through python.

Comment: I suggest to add `python` tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The following awk solution should work:

```
find . | awk -F\. '{ split($2,fils,"/");if (fils[3] != "") { dir[fils[2]]=dir[fils[2]]" \""fils[3]"\"" } else if ( fils[2]!="") { dir[fils[2]]="\""fils[2]"\"" } } END { for ( i in dir ) system("qsub -t 1-[number of lines in list_of_folders.txt] -tc 2 analysis.sh "dir[i]) }'
```

Here we are listing the full paths of filenames allowing us to take the directories as well. We use split to distinguish the directories from the file and then build strings similar to below in the array dir:

"testdir11" "file1" "file2"

"testdir12" "file1" "file2"

The directory and then the files are intentionally quoted to allow the complete string to be passed to the system function along with the command outlined.